# React Navigation V5 hide Bottom tab bar in Stack Navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have found many different solutions, but unfortunately none of them work.
I have a Stack Navigator and a Tabbar Navigator. I have a profile page. Now I want that when you press a button that another screen opens - I managed that. But unfortunately I have the annoying tabbar also in this screen. How do I get rid of it? I think this should work, but React Navigation don't recommend it:

```js
if (route.state && route.state.index > 0) {
  navigation.setOptions({tabBarVisible: false})
} else {
  navigation.setOptions({tabBarVisible: true})
}
```

Comment: Did you try this? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/

Comment: Yeah, I did. It didn't work for me. I get errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a main stack navigator, which will handle the main routing. Then, you need to create another tab navigator and then pass it to the stack screens where you want the tab navigator.
You could try something similar to this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/